# HTML of jQuery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given some HTML:

```
<span class="regular">Turkey</span>
<span class="removed">Ketchup</span>
<span class="added">Bacon</span>
<span class="added">Chicken</span>
<span class="added">Peanut Butter</span>
<span class="added">Mustard</span>
```

I am querying for only the classes with `.added` and `.removed` like so:

```
$(".removed, .added")
```

How do I get the combined HTML of those selected elements? 
I tried (just for laughs)

```
$(".removed, .added").html()
```

This obviously does not work to get the markup (it only provides innerHTML of just the first element). Is there a quicker way than using `.each`?  As a one liner?

I wanted to use the existing classes from the spans to create the output. Since the added and removed classes make the text green and red-with-a-strikethrough respectively. In that case it make's sense for me to pull those DOM elements and reuse them.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I wanted to use the existing classes from the `span`s to create the output. Since the added and removed classes create make the text green and red with a strikethrough.

Comment: *"This obviously does work."* Then what's the problem?

Comment: @FelixKling I suspect that's a typo as the line clearly wouldn't produce what the OP is asking for.

Comment: So, are you expecting a simple string of all of the HTML within each of those classes e.g. `"Ketchup Bacon Chicken"` or an array of objects for each element (the entire element including the surrounding span) e.g. `[span.removed, span.added, span.added]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
var html_string = $('<div />').append($('.removed, .added').clone()).html();
```

I'd write a jQuery plugin and provide that in an external file like I would any 3rd party plugin. Then you can do it as a cleaner "one liner" like you desire.

Plugin definition:

```
(function (global) {
    var $;

    if (global.jQuery) {
        $ = global.jQuery;

        $.fn.combinedHTML = function () {
            return $('<div />').append(this.clone()).html();
        };
    }
}(window));
```

Plugin usage:

```
var html_string = $('.removed, .added').combinedHTML();
```

A JS fiddle using each: http://jsfiddle.net/2y7uG/1/

**TAKE NOTE:** You mentioned at the end of your post that "*it make's [sic] sense for me to pull those DOM elements and reuse them*". Note that getting the HTML of something and using it does not "*pull those DOM elements*" out of the DOM. Because you asked about getting HTML, and such an operation is a read of the DOM without manipulating it, I used `.clone()` in my code such that the append wouldn't change the originals. If you really want to pull out the originals, the whole thing would be a lot simpler by simply appending your collection where you want it in the first place:

```
$('.removed, .added').appendTo('#placeIWantThem');
```

This will result in the elements being pulled from where they are currently in the DOM, and placed where desired. It is simpler, more performant code as well.

Comment: In my situation it does not matter if I pull the spans (move them) vs cloning the spans. Once this function is called the original html will be removed from the screen.

Comment: In that case, then, I would go with a simpler approach...see my edit below the note.

Answer (score 2):

The concatenated html of some mixed elements that can be all over the DOM doesn't make sense.

The text does, though, and `$(".removed, .added").text()` should work.

---

Update: As you have updated the question with what you actually want to achieve, you could do it something like this:

```
$(".removed, .added").clone().appendTo($('.newPlaceToReuse'))
```

Comment: but this would give "KetchupBaconChickenPeanut ButterMustard" . OP wants html.

Comment: op is just having some fun exploring the jQuery api. I tried to explain why html() is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VJvp5/)***

```
var x = "";
$('.removed, .added').each(function () {
    x += this.outerHTML;
});
alert(x)
```

Comment: It's not a one line but probably the only way to do what the OP wants.

Comment: the question is how to get this in one line.

Comment: @Gotschi You remove the spacing ^^

Comment: @Gotschi I am jesting

Answer (score -2):

One way that comes to mind:
**Approach #1**

```
function doSomething(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('clickedTag')){
        // code here
    }

    else {
         // and here
    }
}

$('.tag1').click(doSomething);
$('.tag2').click(doSomething);
```

**Approach #2**

This will also work:

```
​$(".class1, .class2").click(function(){
   alert("clicked");    
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Afg5s/1/

This is fine if your selectors are simple, but I prefer separate functions (approach #1) if there is a chance that logic will be reused.

You can also look at: jQuery multiple class selector for handling multiple classes on the same item.

Comment: This isn't answering the question at all. The OP is trying to get the HTML of each of the two classes